# Google doesn't return time zone for some calendars

Tags: java, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm working with Google Calendar API V3 and have some difficulties with handling time zones provided by Google.
In the documentation for calendar:   [Calendars Overview](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars)

It's said that time zone for calendar is optional field:

> timeZone
>       string
>       The time zone of the calendar. (Formatted as an IANA Time Zone Database 
>       name, e.g. "Europe/Zurich".) Optional.
>   However, it's also optional in CalendarList (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList).

What does Google assume time zone is in case time zone is not specified in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone is assumed to be the time zone set in the calendar itself.

Request:

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary

Response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"LOjlc76YTigzSZVQwSEE/E756z8zuickcYzaOnj8krCN4-Pk\"",
 "id": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "xxx@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
}
```

Created new calendar without setting the timezone results in

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"W8S50vTLOjlc76YTigzSZVQwSEE/cBQwQ2pDeiLoQ406eiNPZrDEINc\"",
 "id": "ddd5qep4g260mm7fgq8vtgp18@group.calendar.google.com",
 "summary": "testone",
 "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
It's said to be Optional. If it's not set, what timezone does Google use? 

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars

Comment: What if you dont set it when creating a new calendar?  UTC.   When creating events its the zone set in the calendar itself.     You know it would almost be faster if you just had tested it yourself instead of asking a question :)